# Unable to extend C drive through command line due to healthy partition

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, virtual-machine, vsphere

I am trying to extend C drive through powershell script. There is 5GB of unallocated space available but I have 2 Healthy Partition Sections between my c dive and the unallocated memory. Thus it is not allowing either manual or command line to expand.

I am not interested in using tools because this is for an automation purpose. If definite tool dependency then i would like to know which tool has integration with powershell.

Comment: If the volume you want to expand is not contiguous with the unallocated space, I feel you will need more than PowerShell to help that situation. There are some tools that allow you to move partitions around, but some things can't be moved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I agree, but this i am working on a end to end automation using powershell to expand c drive. Wanted to find out if there is anyother way that i can achieve this without manual intervention.

Comment: Why aren't you simply able to turn the VM off, apply the drive increase and power back up?

Comment: I know diskpart can extend a partition and can be scripted.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings), you can't perform what you're looking to do because of a lack of contiguous unallocated space.

One workaround, take a look at the [vCenter Converter](https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html). This tool will allow you to take the VM and run it through a conversion process, where you can achieve the end result.

However, if you do that, I would *highly* recommend splitting your partitions into separate VMDKs to avoid this issue in the future.